# Edit entries in MySQL table with HTML form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, edit

I have basic PHP skills (baically, I am able to edit existing code to my own variables)
With that said, I'm looking for a template for sorts to edit one of my MySql tables.

I have a table that has content that is displayed based on the curr_date.  The current page that displays the information is built in ASP.  I need to update the table once a quarter so the correct information is displayed on the correct date.

I found phpMyEdit here: http://www.phpmyedit.org/.  But haven't see any reviews on it or if it will do the job.

Comment: if you are trying to make changes only to MySQL tables then you might want to look into MySQL workbench: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/ if you are looking into creating your own PHP/MySQL application for this then you should post for what you have already done so that someone can help you with the problems there.

Comment: That's the problem. I haven't done anything. I'm looking for a template that is already out there. It seems like a simple process that has already been done.  Right now, the ASP page uses Ultimate Editor to do the job, but that's not PHP compliant.   I just need a template that will pull up the table and give me the ability to edit the date field on the fly from a web page. I understand that I can just do it from phpMyAdmin, but I don't want to give the users that much power.

Comment: you need to try doing something on your own first. That way it would be easier for someone here to help you if you run into any issues with your code.

Answer (score 0):

W3schools.com has some great php/MySQL examples for this.  Here's the intro to php and mysql http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp.  Take a look at that and you should be on your way.